# Probability of the area of triangle POQ?

Tags: probability

In the cartesian plane, selection of a point P along the y axis in [0,2] is uniformly random. Similarly selection of a point Q along the x axis in [0,2] also uniformly distributed. What is the probability of the area of the triangle POQ to be less than or equal to 1, where O is the origin ?

Answer (score 1):

If we call $p$ the length of $OP$, and $q$ the length of $OQ$, we have $pq<2$.

We can interpret this question geometrically.

[image]

What fraction of the $2\times2$ box above is covered by the area $xy<2$?
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{4}\left(2+\int_1^22\ln(x)dx\right)&=\frac{1}{4}\left(2+2\ln(2)\right)\\
&=\frac{1+\ln(2)}{2}
\end{align}

We conclude that the probability is $\displaystyle\frac{1+\ln(2)}{2}$.